# Python Selenium. Can't click a button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to click the "Sign In" button, but I get various errors, like:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Sign In"]"}

Here's the link:
https://e.pilkington.com/ecomm/search/tools

-Code Snippet-

```
login_button = driver.find_element('name','Sign In')
login_button.submit()
```

Code works for a another site so syntax is correct. I know that button's name isn't 'Sign In', but I tried various options like 'linkText' and nothing works.
Can someone help me? Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Xpath instead of Name.

```
login_button =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Sign In']")
login_button.submit()
```

Comment: I bit modified your code and it works! :)
login_button = driver.find_element("xpath","//button[text()='Sign In']")